# md-datepicker not showing up

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I wonder why my md-datepicker is not showing up. I have this html code in the partial html.

```
<div ng-if="question.QuestionTypeId == 4" class="row text-left options" style="">
    <md-datepicker ng-model="foo" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-change="Test(question)"></md-datepicker>
</div>
```

I have the following libs references

```
<script src="~/App/Apps/fnncialQsApp.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/Services/userDataRepo.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/Controllers/fnncialQsCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.css">

<div ng-app="userFinancialData" class="container">
   <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

As the image shown. Only a small hidden square element was displayed.
[image]

Comment: I solved it already as I forgot to inject the material module in my app

Comment: @Wao: any chance you could show the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'ngMaterial' while you initiate the angular module. Given the all other dependent java script files are imported into file, using CDN link or local copy.
Code would look like :

```
angular.module("CustomerManagement", ['ngMaterial']);
```